# Best practice class variables

Tags: php, mysql, class, variables

I have created a `Person` PHP class, and I connected it with MySQL to execute queries.

In the class I use private properties like `$name`, `$age`, etc. and any methods CRUD (INSERT, UPDATE..) and GETTER and SETTER.

When I write these methods is better to pass it like arguments

```
private function insert($name, $age){
  // bindParam uses $name, $age, etc
}
```

or like private proprieties of the class

```
private function insert(){
  // bindParam uses $this->name, $this->age, etc
  ..
}
```

?

I'm asking this because in the first way I need to remember to assign value to each variable (with each setter method), indeed in the second way I pass the value directly.

Comment: Why would your object at once have *state* (stored name, age etc), *and* also accept those same values as parameters to the `insert` function?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's primarily opinion based question, You can architect your application as follow.

First of all a model is only to store a object/entity's data, it should only have getter and setter methods. In your case **Person** is a entity class which hold some properties and getter setter method for each.

Now create another class to perform DB operations of **Person** entity. This class would contain **CRUD** operations. (Insert, Select, Update, Delete) We call this class DAO (**data access object**). [Learn more about DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object).

In **DAO** class at least Insert and Update method will accept **Person**'s object and you use it's getter method to access the value of perticular method. Same way return only **Person**'s object or collection of Person's objects in `SELECT` operation.

This way code will be more maintainable and you can scale it to new level easily.